# convert to grease pencil changes the mesh

Tags: grease-pencil

I have this sqrt of 2 and a plus as an imported svg mesh:

[image]

(yes I know the sqrt is weird, it's a [confirmed bug](https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/issues/105573#issuecomment-900398) in blender)

If I convert that to grease, the mesh changes: it fixes the bug and adds some noise on the plus symbol:

[image]

[image]

The result adding a material + stroke looks weird now:

[image]

Is there another way of doing this? File project is [here](https://we.tl/t-hjIIZgisB8).

Comment: What is your goal? You tried to convert Curve > Grease Pencil to fix the sqrt? Or you need to continue your work with Grease Pencil object? Why don't merge sqrt before import to blender ... it is a one click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say if the issue will occur on every curves.

A manual way to do it:

Go in edit mode and switch the curve direction ("segments/switch direction" menu). Then convert it to grease pencil.

[image]

That could be automated. But how to know this is necessary or not or counterproductive before trying to convert: I don't know.

Comment: Thanks @lemon - how does the final result look in edit mode? for me your solution fixes the +, but not the sqrt overlap problem

Comment: in edit mode, still has separated splines. Here is a test file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=yjllDY82" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/yjllDY82/) and that cannot do more than that, as the original **has** several splines

Answer (score 1):

You can select the grease pencil object, go to Edit mode (point selection mode), select all, choose from menu Stroke > Subdivide, then manually select and delete the unnecessary points.

I also trimmed the x location of a couple of points and added a thickness modifier to set a constant line thickness of 24.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - looking for an automatic way of doing this, as I'll have many equations